# How to use model attribute inside form tag in a jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a jsp form which has model attribute called `projectId`, I want to use it inside form tag as follows.

```
form action="cont/upload?id='${projectId}'" name="createDocumentForm" id="createDocumentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

but it is not recognize by the jsp, what am I doing wrong here?

This is the controller that I set projectId attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/project/task/addNewDocumentSegment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String clinicalProjectDocument(@ModelAttribute("sessionId") String sessionId,@RequestParam("projectId") String projectId,Model model) throws SessionException {
    logger.info("addNewDocumentSegment");
    logger.info(projectId);

    model.addAttribute(projectId, "projectId");
    return "segments/task/addNewDocumentDialog";
}
```

Comment: Where and how did you set your attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake,

```
model.addAttribute(projectId, "projectId");
```

should change as

```
model.addAttribute( "projectId", projectId,);
```